# what is the time complexity to divide two numbers?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Assume that I have two numbers a and b (a>b), and if I divide a by b (i.e. calculate a/b). How much time I need to provide?

Well, People are commenting about the instruction set as well architecture. so here is the assumption.

Assume a and b are two integers each of them has n bits and we have standard x86_64 machine with standard instruction set.

Comment: Hard to say without more details. Could be a single CPU cycle.

Comment: Please specify the architecture, instruction subset if applicable and the numbers' format.

Comment: [Wikipedia may be useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

Comment: There is a conceptual complexity, for the general case.  (Special cases, of course, can be much faster.)  Fundamentally divide is 2-4x slower than multiply with the same size operands, meaning it's the same "big O" complexity, if that's what you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

A request was made to provide an answer rather than just a link, so I will have a go at this. As pointed out by phs above, there is a good link at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division.

Division is one of a number of operations which, as far as computational complexity theory is concerned, are no more expensive than multiplication. One of the reasons for this is that computational complexity theory only really cares about how the cost of an algorithm grows as the amount of data to it gets large, which in this case means multi-precision division. Another is that there is a faster algorithm for division than pen-and-paper long division - this algorithm is in fact good enough to influence the design of computer hardware - famous examples being the Cray-1 reciprocal iteration and the Pentium bug.

The fast way to do division is, instead of dividing a by by, multiply a by 1/b, reducing the problem to computing a reciprocal. To compute 1/b, you first of all scale the problem by powers of two to get b in the range [1, 2), and make a first guess of the answer, typically from a lookup table - the Pentium bug had errors in the lookup table. Now you have an answer with lots of error - you have 1/b + x, where x is the error, which is unknown to you, but small if your lookup table was of a decent size.

The theory of Newton-Raphson iteration for solving equations tells you that if c = 1/b + x is a guess for 1/b, then c(2-bc) is a better guess. If c = 1/b + x then some algebra will tell you that the better guess works out as 1/b -bx^2. You have squared the error x, and since x was small (say 0.1 to start off with) you have roughly doubled the number of bits correct.

You are doubling the number of bits you have correct every time you do this, so it doesn't take many iterations to get a (good enough) answer. Now (here comes the neat part) because you know each iteration is only an approximation anyway, you need only calculate it to the accuracy that you reckon the approximation will give, not the full accuracy of the answer you want. Most of the underlying work is the multiplication in c(2-b) and this grows faster than linear in the number of bits of accuracy you work to. When you sit down and work out the cost of all of this, you find that it grows rapidly enough with the number of digits that you get a sum that looks like 1 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 +... - lots of terms but converging to answer not too far off the very first one - and the cost of a multi-precision divide is not more than a constant factor more than the cost of a multi-precision multiply.

Comment: can't be say if we are dividing a (number of n bits ) by a number b (number of n bits) then the division will take n operations ?

Comment: The best you can expect to do is some constant factor times something over n log n, because a full-precision multiplication will take you something over n log n - see the Wikipedia link phs provided.

Comment: How about if I just care of about quotient's integer part?  Can we do this in O(n) time where n is the number of bits in divisor as well dividend?

Comment: A box that gives me only the integer part of a/b is nearly as powerful as a box that gives me a/b to k binary digits after the binary/decimal point, because I can get that precision by asking it to provide the integer part of (2^k*a)/b, so I don't think you can save time there. You may be able to save time if you require only k bits of precision in the answer. Knuth analyses how to do long division on a computer in Volume 3 section 4.3.1 and there is an analysis there of just how accurate an answer you will get if use only the two leading digits of a and the leading digit of b.

Comment: Thanks Mcdowella, here I am not looking for precision, I just care about the integer division like int/int  gives me an int, The best algorithm I can think of dividing numbers each of n bits takes O(n^2). However I think there must be something better than quadratic.